# Using keyframes with transitionSpec

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

```
val transition = updateTransition(animValue, label = "iconstate")


val offsetVal by transition.animateFloat(
    label = "rocket1 offset"
) { animated ->
   Log.d("Wuh", "AnimatedIconMovement hjhjdahda: $animated")
    if (animated) 1f else 0f
}
val sizeAnimate by transition.animateDp(label ="size dp", targetValueByState = {
    if(it) 60.dp else 20.dp
})
```

MAIN question: how to know if updateTransition has finished? any callback?

Also i want first offsetTo be animated and then on completion sizeAnimate to start, how to do that?

Sorry im new to animations in jetpack compose. do let me know if i can modify.